# Using Boolean on click then checking boolean using if statement to run other code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function and when it's clicked I want other buttons to know it has been clicked and then run their own code, on their own click.

Below is currently what I've tried, but doesn't seem to work. It works if I include the if statement inside of the main document.click but I don't want a click event handler inside another click handler.

```js
var optionalextraClick = false;

$(document).on('click', '.js-optional-extra', function(e) {
  optionalextraClick = true;

  $('#' + $(this).data().productid).css("visibility", "hidden");
  $('#thank-you-' + $(this).data().productid).fadeIn(1800);
});

if (optionalextraClick == true) {
  $('#js-secure-checkout, .modal-close').click(function() {
    location.reload();
  });

  $('#global_modal').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.modal-dialog').length) {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

Once js-optional-extra has been clicked. I would like the other buttons to know it is true, and then when a user clicks on that button it runs that code.

Comment: Is `.js-optional-extra` a checkbox? You also never set `optionalextraClick` back to `false`. In any case, simply move the `if` within both of the two other click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple instead of this -

```
if (optionalextraClick == true) {
   $('#js-secure-checkout, .modal-close').click(function() {
     location.reload();
});

 $('#global_modal').click(function(e) {
   if (!$(e.target).closest('.modal-dialog').length) {
      location.reload();
}
});
```

try this -

```
$('#js-secure-checkout, .modal-close').click(function() {
  if (optionalextraClick == true) {
     location.reload();
 });
```

youre problem is that the click event is never assigned because of the if statement,
when i put the

> if (optionalextraClick == true)

statement inside the event, the event will be created and the code will work, 
do this to both events, hope that makes sense, let me know if something is unclear.

Other than that - i really recommend you check out ReactJS/Angular framework which are abstracting away for you those elements makes web development much simpler and fun.

Comment: thanks for that.. my issue now is that the js-secure-checkout isn't firing but the .modal-close is firing just fine :/

also, how would I include the if statement in the second click event (#global_modal)?

Comment: Ok, i see youre problem, the modal-close element does not yet exist in this context. you should create this only after the modal is created. which you should register to an event line createModal().onModalOpen(function() {...register events } );       does that make sense to you ?